# Weighted average if row header contains

Tags: database, excel

I'm looking for a formula that will return the weighted average of revenue for all the products that contain a "PASSDAYONE"[revenue sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2K09.png)

For now, I am filtering on "PASSDAYONE" then using "sumproduct' This example returns a weighted average of 37,23. Is there a way to have this result returned in one go with a single formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PASSDAYONE",A2:A9))*C2:C9*B2:B9))/SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PASSDAYONE",A2:A9))*B2:B9))
```

[image]

Above formula will first search for the string ***PASSDAYONE*** in the range `A2:A9` and if found will include in `SUMPRODUCT` formula.

Comment: Thank you so much Mrig! It worked absolutely the way I want. Cheers!

Comment: @S.Francotte -Great!